# How to draw a circle on particular tabbed position of the image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, offset, paint, gesturedetector

Currently am working on a flutter project am new to flutter. I need to add a dot on the image in which position I have clicked.

```dart
void gettingPosition(TapDownDetails details) {
  setState(() {
    x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    y = details.globalPosition.dy;
  });
  print("X,Y:$x,$y");
}

GestureDetector(
  onTapDown: gettingPosition,
  child: Container(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
    height: 300,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Image.network(
      "https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/300/911/HD-wallpaper-dark-vertical-black.jpg",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Someone help me to add any color of the dot on the mouse clicking position on the image. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll need to add a child of CustomPaint in your GestureDetector and provide the points that you are clicking from your mouse:

```
void gettingPosition (TapDownDetails details) {
final point = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
setState(() {
  mark.add(point);
});
  }
GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: gettingPosition,
          child: RepaintBoundary(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent),
          image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/skirt.jpg'))),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyCustomPainter(mark),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 ),
```

Then your MyCustomPainter needs to draw those points when you are adding them to your list :

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Offset> marks;
  const MyCustomPainter(this.marks);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) async {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.redAccent
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0;
    canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points, marks, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is ui here (ui.PointMode.points, marks, paint); please clarify me

Comment: That is just the package `import 'dart:ui' as ui;`

Comment: Great to know :)